# Why does a std::vector cause a crash where a std::map doesn't?

Tags: c++, sql-server, freetds

I am trying to work with the new version of freetds (version 0.91).  My code worked fine on version 0.64, but after upgrading, it is giving me pointer errors.  In order to figure out why, I built a stripped down example.  One thing that is really confusing me is that when I use an std::map to store the values, the example code seems to run fine.  But when I switch to storing the values in a vector, I get an invalid pointer error when I call ct_bind:

```
*** glibc detected *** test: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00b06164 ***
```

map code that works:

```
pszColName = (datafmt.namelen) ? datafmt.name : "";
pszColValue = (char*)malloc ((int)(datafmt.maxlength + 1)*sizeof(char));
if (ct_bind (m_pCtCommand, iCol+1, &datafmt, pszColValue, &datalength, &ind) != CS_SUCCEED) {
    return false;
}
queryResults.insert (std::pair<std::string,char*>(pszColName,pszColValue));
```

vector code that crashes:

```
pszColName = (datafmt.namelen) ? datafmt.name : "";
pszColValue = (char*)malloc ((int)(datafmt.maxlength + 1)*sizeof(char));
if (ct_bind (m_pCtCommand, iCol+1, &datafmt, pszColValue, &datalength, &ind) != CS_SUCCEED) {
    return false;
}
names [iCol] = pszColName;
values[iCol] = pszColValue;
```

If this is not enough to fix the problem the full samples are here:

[with map](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TT-zSxCKZdCZlEaU_Oioavm9LaVUxl72mF_r_WtU42U/edit?usp=sharing)

[With vector](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OyZKPn7gPoy7AC4Y0eyBbx2doFISQcTCaIR857L26sQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why using `malloc` in C++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `reserve` on your vectors:

```
names.reserve(num_cols);
values.reserve(num_cols);
```

But that only affects their capacity. It doesn't actually add elements to them. Then, you directly do this:

```
names [iCol] = pszColName;
values[iCol] = pszColValue;
```

on vectors that still have size zero. That is undefined behavior! What you want to do instead is to either initially `resize()` the two vectors to `num_cols` or to just `push_back()` the values:

```
names.push_back(pszColName);
values.push_back(pszColValue);
```

Also, since these two are tightly coupled, you could just have a:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, char*> > values;
```

Other problems in the code include externally counting the vector sizes rather than relying on the `size()` method - which would've initially revealed your problem by returning `0`.